# Loop along a vector for(i in c()) R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have a loop like this:

```
f<-c("a","b","c","d")
h<-c()
for(i in c(3,2,4,1)){
h[i]<-f[i]
}
```

The result is:

```
h
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

But I want:
"c" "b" "d" "a"

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a loop `f[ c(3,2,4,1)]#[1] "c" "b" "d" "a"` would give the answer

Answer (score 3):

We don't need a loop to do this

```
f[c(3,2,4,1)]
#[1] "c" "b" "d" "a"
```

---

If the loop is really required, initialize a `vector` 'h' with the same length as 'f', then loop through the sequence of index, subset the 'f' based on the 'ind' and assign those to each element of 'h'

```
h <- character(length(f))
ind <- c(3, 2, 4, 1)
for(i in seq_along(ind)) {
   h[i] <- f[ind[i]]
}

h
#[1] "c" "b" "d" "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @akrun said you don't need a loop but maybe this is a simplified version of your real problem, so I will try to show what you should do *with* a loop.

What is wrong with your code is that in the loop you are successively setting

```
h[3] <- f[3]
h[2] <- f[2]
h[4] <- f[4]
h[1] <- f[1]
```

when you should be doing

```
h[1] <- f[3]
h[2] <- f[2]
h[3] <- f[4]
h[4] <- f[1]
```

So try the following.

```
f <- c("a","b","c","d")
inx <- c(3,2,4,1)
h <- c()

for(i in 1:4){
    j <- inx[i]
    h[i] <- f[j]
}
```

Or, more simple,

```
for(i in 1:4){
    h[i] <- f[inx[i]]
}
```

Also, if you know the length of the result vector, `h`, you shoudn't create it like that. When you create `h <- c()` this is a vector of length zero, forcing R to extend it each time through the loop.

It is much better to do

```
h <- character(length(f))
```

and then assign values to elements of `h` that already exist.

Comment: This doesn't change the output but just for clarity, your example loop assigns in a different order than the order given by your "what you should be doing" block.

Comment: @Renu You are right, I didn't notice that. What I really meant is `for(i in 1:4)`. Corrected.